# Possibility of finding 3 distinct positive integers whose harmonic mean is an integer

Tags: means

Is it possible to find 3 distinct positive integers a, b, c such that the result a*b*c/(a*b + b*c + ca) is also an integer?

Comment: If you can find two distinct positive integers whose harmonic mean is an integer, you can find an answer to this question. Do you see why?

Comment: @DavidK As 3 = (1+1) + 1, and since for 2 specific positive integers, it is possible to find HM - that is an integer, can it be generalized like this? Or principle of mathematical induction? Not sure, though, what your hint suggests!

Comment: I only had in mind that from two you can get three. The same method does not give you $n+1$ **distinct** numbers from $n$ distinct numbers if $n>2,$ because the harmonic mean of the $n$ numbers might already be in the set of $n$ numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Note that the distinct integers $2, 3, 6$ satisfy $2\cdot 3\cdot 6 = 36$ and $$2\cdot 3 + 2\cdot 6 + 3\cdot 6 = 6 + 12 + 18 = 36$$ so the quotient $$\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot 6}{2\cdot 3 + 2\cdot 6 + 3\cdot 6}$$ is equal to $1$.